# loadLayersModel() or loadGraphModel() for TensorflowJS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

So I followed some tutorial on converting a tensorflow model (downloaded from tensorflow hub) to a tfjs model with binary and json files. When I try to use `loadLayersModel()` it throws a error. When I try to use `loadGraphModel()`, it loads and runs but the predictions dont seem to work or be meaningful in anyway. How can I tell which method to load models? I need some direction on how to troubleshoot or some recommended workflow particularly in tensorflowJS. I am using this in React Native with expo project. not sure if that matters.

TensorflowHub : https://tfhub.dev/google/aiy/vision/classifier/food_V1/1

my code:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
import { bundleResourceIO, decodeJpeg } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const modelJSON = require('./TFJS/model.json')
const modelWeights = require('./TFJS/group1-shard1of1.bin')


export const loadModel = async () => {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
        bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights)
    ).catch((e) => {
        console.log("[LOADING ERROR] info:", e)
    })
    return model
}

export const transformImageToTensor = async (uri)=>{
    //read the image as base64
      const img64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {encoding:FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64})
      const imgBuffer =  tf.util.encodeString(img64, 'base64').buffer
      const raw = new Uint8Array(imgBuffer)
      let imgTensor = decodeJpeg(raw)
      const scalar = tf.scalar(255)
    //resize the image
      imgTensor = tf.image.resizeNearestNeighbor(imgTensor, [192, 192])
    //normalize; if a normalization layer is in the model, this step can be skipped
      const tensorScaled = imgTensor.div(scalar)
    //final shape of the rensor
      const img = tf.reshape(tensorScaled, [1,192,192,3])
      return img
  }



export const getPredictions = async (image)=>{
    await tf.ready()
    const model = await loadModel()
    const tensor_image = await transformImageToTensor(image)
    // const predictions = await makePredictions(1, model, tensor_image)
    const prediction = await model.predict(tensor_image)
    console.log(prediction)
    console.log(prediction.datasync()[0])
    return prediction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a layers model, you you 'loadLayersModel `and if its a graph model, you use 'loadGraphModel` - they are NOT interchangable and you CANNOT load a model using different method.

So if it loads using `loadGraphModel`, it is a graph model - as simple as that.

> the predictions dont seem to work or be meaningful in anyway

This does not help - what do you expect and what do you actually get?

Comment: how do i know if the tfhub module i downloaded is a layers or graph model? I want the index of the maxvalue. i tried using tf.argmax but it returns undefined

Comment: if it loads using `loadGraphModel` without errors, its a graph model. if it were not a graph model, load would fail. And opposite for layers. As simple as that. And again, you DID NOT say what your result from execute is.